# Addition operation by user input value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie for the Python. Here I'm trying to add two value by using

```
x = 10
y= 20
print("Addition value is ", x+y )
```

## It's return the proper result as: Addition value is 30.

But while I'm read the input by the user by using input() . It's just concatenate the x and y value. For ex)

```
x = input('Enter first number:')
y = input('Enter the second number')
z = x + y
print("The addition value is:",z)
```

Imagine if I give user input for first number as 10 second number as 20 means

## It's return the result as "The addition value is: 1020

I'm not sure why it's concatenate the two values instead of adding two values
Is I did any mistake on my code. Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to:

```
x = int(input('Enter first number:'))
y = int(input('Enter the second number'))
z = x + y
print("The addition value is:",z)
```

**Reasoning**:

The `type` of user input(`input` method) is always `string`. 
If you perform `+` on strings it will concatenate both values instead of adding.
So first convert them into int(or float)

Comment: Thanks for your quick attention on these  May I know why we need to specify as int() here ?

Comment: See the reasoning part. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will take look on these

Comment: @Kannan.P Read the duplicate, `input()` always returns a string in Python 3, which you are clearly using- next time don't tag your question with both python versions

Comment: Sure @Chris_Rands. I will keep in mind for my next level of questions :)